# PHP foreach inside XML string syntax

Tags: php, xml, loops, foreach, syntax

I have a variable, in which is a XML string.

In this XML string, I want **iterate through a variable `$items`**, and make number of `<item>` elements in XML...I do not know the right syntax though...I am trying somethign like this, but it isn't working at all.

Thank you for advice

```
    // Not empty, array of numerous elements, just for example
    // and imagination of array here.
    $items = [];
    $variable =  
         '<soap:Envelope>
              <soap:Header>
                  <F2SoapHeader>
                      <login>login</login>
                      <psw>psw</psw>
                  </F2SoapHeader>
              </soap:Header>
              <soap:Body>
                  <method>
                      <items>
                          <?php foreach ($items as $item){ ?>
                              <item>
                                  '. $item .' 
                              </item>
                          <?php } ?>
                      </items>
                  </methods>
              </soap:body>
          </soap:Envelope>';
```

Comment: Why,  [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) not work?

Comment: you had the right idea with breaking out of the single quotes for `$item`, but your `foreach` is still inside the string for the variable `$variable`. Also, using `<?php ...` inside of what appears to be PHP is not going to work.

Comment: `...<items>';` then `foreach ....` then `$variable .= "<item>{$item}</item>";` than the rest.

Comment: That said, I'll echo @ArtisticPhoenix, there are already multiple XML tools built into PHP: [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) and [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php)

Comment: I have always had good luck with XMLWriter as you can flush the memory if you have a large file etc...  So I never bothered creating my own tools.

Answer (score 0):

Everything between `<?php` and `?>` is php
Everything outside `<?php` and `?>` will be outputed by the server.

Therefore the soap output must be kept outside `<?php` and `?>`:

```
    <?php
        // Not empty, array of numerous elements, just for example
        // and imagination of array here.
        $items = [] 
    ?> 
        <soap:Envelope>
            <soap:Header>
                <F2SoapHeader>
                    <login>login</login>
                    <psw>psw</psw>
                </F2SoapHeader>
            </soap:Header>
            <soap:Body>
                <methods>
                    <items>
                        <?php foreach ($items as $item){ ?>
                            <item>
                                <?php $item ?> 
                            </item>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </items>
                </methods>
            </soap:body>
        </soap:Envelope>
```